# Remover primeiro elemento de uma lista encadeada simples

Tags: c, c++

Gostaria de fazer uma função para remover o primeiro elemento de uma lista encadeada, do jeito que fiz ele só está removendo o primeiro nó e removendo o segundo elemento.

```
struct lista {
int info;
struct lista* prox;
};
typedef struct lista Lista;    

Lista* removeInicio(Lista *l){
if(l->prox == NULL){
    printf("Lista ja esta vazia\n");
    return NULL;
}else{
    Lista *tmp = l->prox;
    l->prox = tmp->prox;
    return tmp;
}

}
```

Edit: Resolvi com esse algorítimo.

```
Lista* removeInicio(Lista *l){
Lista* pointer = l->prox;
if(l->prox == NULL){
    printf("Lista ja vazia\n\n");
    return NULL;
}
l->prox = pointer-> prox;
free(pointer);
l->info--;}
```

Comment: A função que tem dá perfeitamente para remover um elemento mas falta o `free` e tem de ser chamada da forma correta com `minhaLista = removeInicio(minhaLista);`. Uma solução mais idiomática em C é a resposta do Claudio Lopes passando o endereço do ponteiro e não fazendo com base em retornos.

Answer (score 3):

Ao passar por referência, não precisa de retornar a Lista.

```
void deletefirst (struct Lista **head) {
   struct Lista *tmp = *head;            
   if (tmp == NULL) return;             
   *head = tmp->next;                 
   free (tmp);                          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar o tipo lógico (booleano) da biblioteca stdbool.h para retornar verdadeiro se deu certo a remoção. E fica mais compreensível o código se tiveres a representação de um nodo.

```
typedef struct nodo {
    int info;
    struct nodo* prox;
}Nodo;

typedef struct lista {
    Nodo *primeiro; 
}Lista;    

bool removeInicio(Lista *lista){
   if(lista->primeiro == NULL){
      printf("Lista ja vazia\n\n");
      return false;
   }
   Nodo *removido = lista->primeiro;

   lista->primeiro = lista->primeiro-> prox;
   free(removido);
   return true; 
}
```